# Windows cache and temp on RAM disk

Tags: windows, cache, ramdisk, temporary-files

I have 16 GB of memory and have just started to experiment with having a 1 GB RAMdisk. Currently, I only have the browser cache there, but I am thinking of moving the Windows7 cache and temp directories to my RAM disk as well. I would like to do this to reduce the wear on my SSD and also for potential performance gains.

I prefer not to copy the data from my RAMdisk to my SSD before shutting down the computer. Is it safe to move these Windows directories or are there times when software (program updates maybe) need to store some files in these directories and then access them after a reboot of the system? This is the only situation I could think of where it can be dangerous to have moved the cache/temp files to volatile storage, but I am not if this situation ever arises. If someone could enlighten me, that would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The only catch you may want to watch for is `%temp%` is actually user dependent by default. Normally it points at `C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Temp`.

Comment: I wouldn't suggest this. Temp directories are used to hold cleanup and installer programs across reboots.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I will refrain moving the temp directories then. What about cache? Is that safe to move or also used across reboots?

Comment: You're better off just letting Windows manage your RAM.  A RAMdisk is almost always a terrible idea.